# \textbf has wider space than \bf with own command

Tags: macros, spacing

How come the `\textbf` command results in a wider space between words, than the deprecated `\bf` when using this own command?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}    
    \makeatletter
        \newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{
            \edef\@currentlabel{#1}
            \phantomsection
            #1\label{#2}
        }
    \makeatother

\begin{description}
    \item[item] \textbf{\textlabel{First text}{ref1}} \\
    Description!
    \item[item] {\bf \textlabel{Second text}{ref2}} \\
    Description!
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have three spurious spaces in your definition of `\textlabel`. If you remove them by masking the end-of-lines, the result is the same:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\textlabel}[2]{% <- Here
  \edef\@currentlabel{#1}% <- Here
  \phantomsection
  #1\label{#2}% <- Here
}
\makeatother
```

Why don't the spaces show up in the second case? Because `\textbf` starts a paragraph by itself, while `\bf` doesn't. So in the second case the spaces are ignored because TeX is still not typesetting a paragraph.

The correct command to use with a syntax similar to `\bf` is `\bfseries`: it's a declaration, so it needs a pair of braces or it can be issued in an environment. But it's preferable to use `\textbf` in running text: you can see a difference between

```
{\bf stuff} boldfaced
```

and

```
\textbf{stuff} boldfaced
```

because in the second case LaTeX adds the "italic correction" that compensates for the "f" bumping into the interword space.

Comment: Perhaps add a hint that `\bfseries` features the same behaviour as the obsolete `\bf`.

Comment: @lockstep
But the \bfseries needs including a package right?

Comment: @egreg
Awesome. Learned something new again. This actually just happened today, because I had comments after each line and wanted to make the comments look nice, but having a space between the code and the '%' comment symbol. Silly me.

Comment: @lockstep I wouldn't recommend using `\bfseries` in that situation.

Comment: @egreg But would you recommend `\bf`? (My hint was mainly about that the OP's problem is not due to using an obsolete command.)

Comment: @cherrung `\bfseries` doesn't need a package.

Comment: @lockstep Done. Of course I *deprecate* using `\bf`. ;-)